# Extend filesystem and LVM

Tags: rhel, lvm, resize2fs

I need to add more space to my filesystem.

Right now it looks like this :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/mapper/vg_dcqsvu009-lv_root

                       50G   47G   16M 100% /

tmpfs                 8.0G  1.5G  6.6G  18% /dev/shm

/dev/sda2             477M   41M  411M   9% /boot

/dev/sda1             200M  276K  200M   1% /boot/efi

/dev/mapper/vg_dcqsvu009-lv_home

                      1.7T  2.8G  1.6T   1% /home
```

I ran the lvextend command on vg_dcqsvu009-lv_root and it shows extended         when I run a lvdisplay.
But on the filesystem itself, the added space is not showing up.

After some digging I found out I had to use "resize2fs" command on my filesystem, so basically run this command :

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_dcqsvu009-lv_root
```

My questions are :

- is this right ?
- can I do this while keeping the server online ?
- what are the implications ?

This is a RHEL 6.9

Thanks

Comment: You can grow the ext4 partition online: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ext4grow

Comment: It depends on the filesystem you're using for lv-root. As an example, an ext4 filesystem and be *increased* in size without having to un-mount it; online. The `man` page for each filesystem usually explains whether it can be resized online.

Answer (score 0):

You are right and the command resize2fs should be executed to resize the file system, RHEL6.x uses ext4 by default, so it's an online task and it doesn't need to unmount or not require system downtime.